# open .dbi files with PHP

Tags: php, dbi, foxpro

i want to open a .dbi file with PHP. i cant find anything about this on google. maybe some guys of you can help me?

is there maybe a snippet to grab the data structure from a dbi file?

thanks!

Comment: Which program has created the file in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using an import tool, importing the DBI file into a MySQL database. That way you can access the data using regular MySQL functions in PHP.

I believe Navicat imports DBI files:

http://www.navicat.com/